# Get data from component

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I have component: ckeditor. I am trying to get data from it and save it to the database. Every time I save the data using the store function I get an empty record in the database:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $business = Business::create($request->all());
        if($request->has('photos')) {
            foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
                $filename = $photo->store('public/photos');
                Photo::create([
                    'business_id' => $business->id,
                    'filename' => $filename
                ]);
            }
        }
        return redirect()->action('BusinessController@clist');
    }
```

Here is my code of component:

```
<template>
<vue-ckeditor type="classic" v-model="editorData" :editors="editors" id="description" name="description"></vue-ckeditor>
</template>

<script>
    import VueCkeditor from 'vue-ckeditor5'

    export default {
        components: {
            'vue-ckeditor': VueCkeditor.component
        },
        data(){
            return {
                editors: {
                    classic: ClassicEditor
                },
                editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

The code in create.blade.php:

```
<vue-ck name="description" id="description"></vue-ck>
```

I will just add that the store function works fine for textarea input. Thanks for help guys.

---

Model:

```
class Business extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'order',
        'visible',
        'lang'
    ];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Photo::class); 
    }
}
```

I have additional columns there, title, lang etc. But the important column is a description. I do not know why I do not want to download data from this component.

Comment: In your code I don't see where you define `photos`, therefore I think that the photos are in fact not in the request. Is there something missing in your code examples?

Comment: in general, photos are not relevant here, and in fact only the line that gets all the values ​​from input fields $business = Business::create($request->all()); 
please check my edit

Comment: Try to check if `description` is really in the request. You should also check your source code to see, if the `name` attribute gets outputted correctly for further debugging.